# Apache error - PHP configured - resuming normal operations [MAC]

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've reinstalled apache and php using brew a few times and have gotten no where.
Currently my error log keeps showing:

```
[Sun Jan 10 22:40:01.548345 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 35970] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Sun Jan 10 22:40:01.578572 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 35970] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/7.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 10 22:40:01.578609 2016] [core:notice] [pid 35970] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.16/bin/httpd'
```

My localhost server is working fine and displays the 'It Works!!!' page.
However, when I try to load a standard phpinfo page, it just displays the code. I'm guessing that's happening because of the errors above, so any suggestions to fix this ?

Comment: Those are not errors, they are notices. They inform you that apache has restarted, nothing more. Check your Apache config if the correct handler is configured for .php files. There should be a line like this somewhere in the config: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: There isn't any line like that; Also if its not a error, what do you think is causing my php page to display the code rather then loading the phpinfo() code

Comment: Then add that line to the config. Without it Apache doesn't know how to handle the file and just serves its source code.

Comment: That fixed it; thanks dude